# Daemon thread spawning user threads: what happens when JVM shuts down?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm wondering what would happen in the following scenario:

Let's say I have the need to monitor some log file and roll it occasionaly. For that purpose I make a daemon thread that runs in while(true) loop, occasionaly spawning the user threads that close the file and open a new one if needed.

But what happens when, at some point all user threads terminate and JVM decides it is time to shut down and initiates the shutdown sequence, but before it actually shuts down, my daemon spawns another user thread? Can this even happen? If it can, will the user thread just die like a daemon or does jvm have some mechanisms to prevent this?

Comment: Well, what happens when you *try it*?

Comment: Really, how do I make my daemon thread spawn user thread just at the moment JVM starts to shut down?

Comment: I mean, aside from the fact that you'd just need to have one *running*, it's kinda a binary thing; either your thread that's spawning threads is running, or it's not. If it is, it's capable of spawning new threads. Any threads set as daemon threads are abruptly terminated when the JVM shuts down. Threads that aren't ... will prevent the JVM from shutting down.

Comment: So if thread is either running or not, when jvm starts a shutdown sequence does it stop the world, or does it let other threads to run a while longer? If first is true than above scenario cannot happen and we're safe to have daemons spawn user threads, otherwise, daemons should not spawn user threads as spawned threads can also be abruptly terminated on JVM shutdown, which is not what you want for a user thread.

Comment: Do you understand that a daemon thread is specific *kind* of thread in Java? That you specify when you create it? It's unclear what my last comment doesn't cover otherwise.